# SQL break into 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field name called 'stuff'
and some records like this

```
info,caow~13909~182029~10593~H7Q0B7MM
info,caow~4964~152073~16863~MF4B8MBC
info,caow~590~265~517~H7Q0B7MM
```

My goal is to break into 3 columns like this

```
columnA   ColumnB   ColumnC
13909     182029    10593
4964      152073    16863
590       265       517
```

Need your help please. Thank you.

Comment: Do you care what the ordering is

Comment: no order number need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option using a little XML

**Example**

```
Select B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'~','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Pos2    Pos3    Pos4
13909   182029  10593
4964    152073  16863
590     265     517
```

**EDIT - Slightly thinner version**

```
Select B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,'~','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

Comment: I have 50000 records like this.

Comment: @ngoc  To be clear, the (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.    The performance is really pretty good.   Try top 5000 records from your actual table

Comment: @ngoc performance can be tweaked a bit if you can gtd XML safe characters

Comment: @ngoc  See edit for "thinner" version.   This is provided you have XML safe characers

Comment: @ngoc Curious, both worked on my end.  It is rare that I post code without testing first  :)

Comment: I tried the Thinner version and worked perfectly. Can you see why Sample 1 not working?

Comment: @ngoc  This is sample 1 working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6e5548e8124042519eac32a6429210aa

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the ordering, you can use:

```
select s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value3
      from (select s.value,
                   row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from string_split(t.col, '~') s
            where s.value not like '%[^0-9]%'
           )
    ) s;
```

Actually, if you don't have duplicates, you can use:

```
row_number() over (order by (select charindex(s.value, t.col)) as seqnum
```

for the `seqnum` definition.

Comment: Little confuse using your query. If my query like this Select stuff from GetDetail then how I would match with your query. Thx

Comment: select s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value3
      from (select s.stuff, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from GetDetails(t.col, '~') s
            where s.varstring not like '%[^0-9]%'
           )
    ) s;      then got error  Incorrect syntax near ')'.